# how to add a class css in a form select on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are some other questions like this, but they didn't work for me. I appreciate any contribution or help.

```
<%= f.select(:status) do %>
    <% [['Activo', 1], ['Inactivo', 2]].each do |c| -%>
    <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I want to add bootstrap form-control class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` takes two options hashes, the second for html options.

To build on your example code in a single (long) line:

```rb
= f.select :status, [['Activo', 1], ['Inactivo', 2]].each { |c| content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) }, {}, class: "form-control"
```

This produces the same HTML as:

```rb
= f.select :status, [['Activo', 1], ['Inactivo', 2]], {}, class: "form-control"
```

[select docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `options_for_select` to add the options and use third argument to add `html options`

```
<%= f.select :status, options_for_select([['Activo', 1], ['Inactivo', 2]]), {}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
```